# Vue Router mimic native mobile tabs and history stack

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to mimic native mobile routing with tabs using Vue Router. To clarify, [by tabs I mean this](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/2013/09/chris-tabbar-400.png).

#### What I am doing now

Right now, all my tabs use `$router.push({ name: tab.tab })` when clicked. I cannot use `router-link` due to using [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com) and it's `ion-button`. Each tab has a group of children. Here is an example where *Learn* is a tab having a *Menu* child:

```
{
  path: '/learn',
  component: () => import('../views/Learn/Learn.vue'),
  children: [
    { path: '', name: 'learn', redirect: {name: 'learn.menu'} },
    {
      path: 'menu',
      name: 'learn.menu',
      component: () => import('../views/Learn/LearnMenu.vue'),
    },
    // etc
```

All the tab parents look almost the same. The `Learn.vue` is basically just this (omitted some transition logic etc):

```
<transition name="blabla">
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view />
  </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

This results in when clicking a tab, i.e. *Learn* in this case, the router takes me to the *LearnMenu*. What I want is when you click a tab button, it opens that parent, and since we are using keep-alive, the state should be same as when leaving that tab.

Right now, if I enter the *Learn* tab, scroll or change child, then switch to another tab and hit the browser's back button, it does exactly that. But instead, I want that to happen from a button, and not necessarily just take me one step back.

#### An alternative?

It might be possible to split up all tabs into different routers instead. Then having a `<component :is="currentTab" />`. Then when clicking a tab  button it could just switch `currentTab`. However, then it wouldn't be possible to link between the tabs like: `$router.push({ name: 'anotherTab.bla })`.

#### Conclusion

I might be thinking about this completely wrong and there might already be something written about this topic. Although I haven't found anything, so I am asking here instead. Thanks.

> How do I mimic the native mobile routing behaviour where each tab has its own history and state?

Comment: Have to tried using one parent component with multiple components (tabs) in it and v-shows (so each tab stays in dom including it's state)? You can then push query string changes to router (all on parent component) to update history but not necessary re-render the page.

Comment: That sounds a bit like my alternative solution. But how would you go about linking between the tabs, and also parsing the incoming url, eg: my-app.com/some/deep/link?

Comment: I've got no experience with this; just remember reading about it in the docs; checkout: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes (so change something that triggers the v-show in the watch method of your parent component)